# Unable to paginate with selenium-scrapy, only extracting data for first page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

I am scraping a website for most recent customer rating, with several pages.

The problem is that I am able to interact with the "sortby" option and select "most recent" using Selenium, and scrape data for first page using Scrapy. However, I am unable to extract the data for other pages, the Selenium Web driver somehow does not render the next page. My intension is to automate data scraping.

I am a newb to web scraping. A snippet of the code is attached here (Some information is removed due to confidentiality)

```
import scrapy
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait,Select
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapy import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class ABC(scrapy.Spider):
    #"........."
   

    def start_requests(self):
        #"  ......  "

            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
         settings =get_project_settings()
         driver_path = settings.get('EDGE_DRIVER_PATH')
         options = Options()
         options.add_argument("headless")
            
         ser=Service(driver_path)
         driver = webdriver.Edge(service=ser,options = options)

         driver.get(response.url)
         WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"sort-order-dropdown")))
         element_dropdown=driver.find_element(By.ID,"sort-order-dropdown")
         select=Select(element_dropdown)
         select.select_by_value("recent")
         time.sleep(5)

            for review in response.css('[data-hook="review"]':
               res={
                   "rating": review.css('[class="a-icon-alt"]::text').get(),
                 }
               yield res 
                     
            
         next_page =response.xpath('//a[text()="Next page"]/@href').get()
         if next_page:
             yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
       
         driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks that you're using Scrapy and Selenium instead of `scrapy_selenium` (I don't see any `SeleniumRequest` in your code.

Your current spider works like this:

1. Get page using Scrapy
2. Get the same page using Selenium webdriver
3. Perform some actions using Selenium
4. Parse **Scrapy** `response` (for `rating` and `next_page`)

As you see you never use / parse Selenium result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right, I am not using SeleniumRequest. Can you please elaborate on how to incorporate SeleniumRequest in the present script.